# How can I edit dingo/api auth middleware in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, dingo-api

In a fully restful Laravel project, I'm using [**`dingo/api`**](https://github.com/dingo/api/wiki) package. I need to set some configs and other stuff related to current user, before any request get handled. When we using dingo, we can access the current user like this:

```
$user = app('Dingo\Api\Auth\Auth')->user();
```

First I thought that I should do this in a service provider. But in there the Laravel has not yet initiated the dingo authenticating, therefore it's throw me an error. Then I thought I need to edit the dingo auth middleware called `api.auth` to do this. Its Usage on my routes is like this:

```
<?php

$api = app('Dingo\Api\Routing\Router');

$api->version('v1', ['prefix' => 'v1', 'namespace' => 'App\Http\Controllers'], function ($api) {

    $api->group(['prefix' => 'admin', 'middleware' => 'api.auth'], function ($api) {

        $api->get('checkRole/{branch_id}', 'RoleController@getRoles');
```

But I don't have any access to it because it's a builtin middleware in dingo package. So what should I do in this situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this at its own time but I forgot to answer it here.
I simply extended the digo auth middleware and overrode its `handle` method. But I had to replace the middleware name through all the route files in the project (I'm using `nwidart/laravel-modules` package to write a modular project).

```
<?php

    namespace App\Http\Middleware;

    use Closure;
    use Dingo\Api\Http\Middleware\Auth;

    class ApiAuth extends Auth
    {
        public function handle($request, Closure $next)
        {
            $route = $this->router->getCurrentRoute();

            if (!$this->auth->check(false))
                $this->auth->authenticate($route->getAuthenticationProviders());

            ...
            ...

            return $next($request);
        }
    }
```